# Images not changing inside the iPhone simulator

Tags: objective-c, xib

I'm currently working on my app and I was editing the settings image. Somehow the old image is still shows up on the simulator and the new one on the XIB.

[If you look at this image you can see it closely](http://gyazo.com/f438c7bdec8607d8dc6a18488f480980.png)

**EDIT:**

I re-saved and re-named the image and added it back to the project and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably clean your project. This happens often.

Press `Cmd + Shift + K` to clean the project and `Cmd + Alt + Shift + K` to clean build directory.

Comment: I cleaned the project and everything but the same old image still shows up. My source files are hosted on my dropbox, not sure if that changes anything

Comment: You mean that your project folder is on Dropbox right? That doesn't matter. Then try checking all the sizes of the icons, deleting and then adding them again. That should help.